# JavaScript: Show element under Form after submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form and I want to show some content after someone has entered their email and submit the form. The form should hide and the content should become visible.

I have written some JavaScript but when we type the email and submit the form, the page refreshes and form is back on the content.

The JavaScript I have partially works for the `onClick` event, however it is still not complete:

```js
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("formhide");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
  x.style.display = "block";
} else {
  x.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 300px;
}

form {
  margin: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<form id="formhide" method="post">
  <input type="email" name="email-address" required>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
</form>

<div>
  <h2>ESKETIT</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia voluptatibus excepturi voluptates ratione aut placeat in maxime obcaecati reprehenderit! Modi provident nulla nostrum obcaecati esse, tempore commodi excepturi quae culpa.</p>
</div>
```

Someone submit email to form, form will hide and show content for long time.

Comment: When the form is submitted the page is reloaded.

Comment: okey but is it possible?

Comment: send form data via `ajax` without page reload.

Comment: if you do that the form will not show to the user if someone has submitted once. You might have to figure out the alternative to grab the user information and check if that user has already submitted the form than dont show it or else like first timers show the form

Comment: so how we can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve what you're wanting. Typically, an AJAX-like request posts form data to the server via JavaScript which means you can then update the document's HTML once the AJAX request has completed.

One way to achieve this with your code would be via the [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) method, and [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) object as shown below:

```js
function myFunction(event) {

  /* Prevent button causing default browser submit */
  event.preventDefault();

  /* Get form element */
  const form = document.getElementById('formhide');

  /* Create form data object from form element which contains post data */
  let formData = new FormData(form);

  /* Issue "ajax request" to server. Change /post-to-url to the appropriate 
  url on your server */
  fetch('/post-to-url', {
      body: formData,
      method: "post"
    })
    .then(function() {
      /* When submit successfully completed, hide form */
      form.style.display = "none";

      /* Show success message */
      const successMessage = document.getElementById('success-message');
      successMessage.style.display = 'block';

    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log('Error', error);
    });


}
```

```css
#success-message {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="formhide" method="post">
  <input type="email" name="email-address" required>
  <button onclick="myFunction(event)">Click Me</button>
</form>

<p id="success-message"> Form sent - this is the message that displays after submit </p>

<div>
  <h2>ESKETIT</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia voluptatibus excepturi voluptates ratione aut placeat in maxime obcaecati reprehenderit! Modi provident nulla nostrum obcaecati esse, tempore commodi excepturi quae culpa.</p>
</div>
```